# Skype for Desktop Apps

Tags: skype, skypedeveloper, skype4com

I'm developing and distributing a communication software for disabled people since years.

These handicapped people prefer to have everything in one application (eMails, internet, Skype, etc.).

Therefore I've used the Skype4COM library. 
It all worked fine for years, then suddenly it wouldn't work anymore (I think it was in 2014), then shortly after, it worked again.

Now - using Windows 10 with the integrated Skype application - it doesn't work anymore.

I'm getting the error "Skype client is not installed" in this line:

```
Set oSkype = New SKYPE4COMLib.Skype'works fine
oSkype.Client.Start True, True 'raises error "Skype client is not installed"
```

I've tried to get some information about this on the docs, but I didn't find the required information.

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong or what I have to do differently in order to allow the user to use Skype in my communication software again?

Comment: @RichardTaylor Richard, do you know who could answer this question?

Comment: I think you're out of luck :( It's not that you're doing anything wrong, just that the Universal Windows Platform version of Skype doesn't support Skype4COM. I don't think there's a replacement either.